# java creating smooth multi image animation

Tags: java, canvas, jframe, desktop

I've been looking through/for guides all night trying to find how to smooth out my multiple image animation. I tried a few guides, found one i liked but it's quite choppy.

atm my animation works but flashes.

my animation clas:

```
package graphics;
```

import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animation {

```
private ArrayList<OneScene> scenes;
private int sceneIndex;
private long movieTime;
private long totalTime;

//Constructor
public Animation() {
    scenes = new ArrayList<OneScene>();
    totalTime = 0;
    start();
}

//Add scene to ArayList & set time for each scene
public synchronized void addScene(Image i, long t) {
    totalTime += t;
    scenes.add(new OneScene(i, totalTime));
}

//Start animation
public synchronized void start() {
    movieTime = 0;
    sceneIndex = 0;
}

//Change Scenes
public synchronized void update(long timePassed) {
    if (scenes.size() > 1) {
        movieTime += timePassed;
        if (movieTime >= totalTime) {
            movieTime = 0;
            sceneIndex = 0;
        }
        while(movieTime > getScene(sceneIndex).endTime) {
            sceneIndex++;
        }
    }
}

//Get animation (Image) current scene
public synchronized Image getImage() {
    if (scenes.size() ==0) {
        return null;
    }else{
        return getScene(sceneIndex).pic;
    }
}

//Get Scene
private OneScene getScene(int x) {
    return (OneScene)scenes.get(x);
}

//Private Class
public class OneScene {
    Image pic;
    long endTime;

    public OneScene(Image pic, long endTime) {
        this.pic = pic;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

& a few of my methods:

```
Image load1 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"1.png").getImage();
    Image load2 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"2.png").getImage();
    Image load3 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"3.png").getImage();
    Image load4 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"4.png").getImage();
    Image load5 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"5.png").getImage();
    Image load6 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"6.png").getImage();
    Image load7 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"7.png").getImage();
    Image load8 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"8.png").getImage();
    Image load9 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"9").getImage();
    Image load10 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"10.png").getImage();
    Image load11 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"11.png").getImage();
    Image load12 = new ImageIcon(""+cachemainDir+"12.png").getImage();
    Anim = new Animation();
    Anim.addScene(load1, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load2, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load3, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load4, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load5, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load6, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load7, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load8, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load9, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load10, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load11, 100);
    Anim.addScene(load12, 100);
```

and...

```
        while (AppLoading) {
        long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
        cumTime += timePassed;
        Anim.update(timePassed);

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        draw(g);
        g.dispose();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(0);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

lastly....

```
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
    new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.drawImage(Anim.getImage(), 300, 300, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by flashing? Is there a blank frame between the actual frames? (You can test this by just making a few stills and animating them.)It could be that you are updating to little frames, as you only have 12. This is fine if the images are animated correctly out side of run time. Make the 'cachemainDir' images closer in animation. It *may* help if you `Thread.sleep(5); //or a  number besides 0`

Comment: They are flashing like they disappear for about 1-5 milliseconds. Once it has gone through all 12 Images the image flashes.

Comment: It is hard to tell the exactly where the problem is, but try changing the way you get the current index to draw, I feel like you are rendering a non-existent image. I will keep look though.